# Compare coefficients of two independent variable from two regressions models with the same dependent variable

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I have the two following regression:
$$y=X_1\beta_1+\varepsilon_1$$
and
$$y=X_2\beta_2+\varepsilon_2$$

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are indicator variables and very similar. One expert claim that the two coefficients are the same. I want to know what kind of test I can perform to see if $β_1=β_2$.

Comment: Something like this? $Z=((β_1-β_2)/√(S_(β_1)^2+S_(β_2) ))^2 $

Comment: Note that you can wrote $S_{\beta_1}^2$ in MathJax. Right-click on this notation, then chose "Show Math As" from the menu, then choose "TeX Commands", and you will see the code.

Comment: You refer to $X_1$ and also to $x_1.$ Are those two different things?

Comment: So far I'm the only one who's up-voted this question, although someone else has answered. That tends to be neglected.

Comment: X1 and x1 are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the two predictors are orthogonal, an optimal test is to compare the model

$$ y_i \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2  $$

with the submodel

$$ y_i \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1 (X_1 + X_2)  $$

with the likelihood ratio test. The null hypothesis is that $\beta_1 = \beta_2$.

Comment: My main problem is that the two variable are highly correlated and I want to test if they are different and pick one of them in my model.

Comment: If they're highly correlated, you may just reduce it to a single variable with PCA. There's no need to do what you're asking.

Comment: @StudentT, Not sure there's any point in doing PCA on two binary variables. The combination can only take on four values.

Comment: @user150086, if they are that closely related, the difference in effect size probably isn't large, so you will have low power to detect a statistically significant difference between their effects no matter what you do. You could just pick the one with a larger effect size, or the one that optimizes some predictive criteria.

Comment: If you want to talk about a likelihood ratio test, you have to assume something about the distribution of $\varepsilon_i.$

Comment: Yes @MichaelHardy. I assumed we were talking about the normal errors linear model, where you could use a LRT or an F test.

Answer (score 0):

You are analyzing a single model $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$.  The regression model will return $y=\beta_0+X_1\beta_1$ with $\beta_0$ being the intercept.  To determine the difference between the two models you need to look at both the slope $\beta_1$ and the intercept $\beta_0$.  You can use the indicator variable as a regressor by itself and in combination with your other independent variables.  If the indicator variable is $d$ it will be $d=0$ for the $X_1$s you include above and $d=1$ for the $X_2$s.  The model becomes $y\sim d, X, (X*d)$.  The regression will return $y=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\beta_2d+\beta_3Xd$.  When $d=0$ the coefficients $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ vanish.  When $d=1$ the intercept is $(\beta_0+\beta_2)$ and the slope is $(\beta_1+\beta_3)X$.  Keep the $\beta$s with significant p-values and you end up with a model that tells exactly what and where is the difference between the two groups.  See [Ways of comparing linear regression interepts and slopes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232040/ways-of-comparing-linear-regression-interepts-and-slopes/232041#232041).