# What kind of regression can I run for categorical independent variables and continuous dependent variable?

Tags: r, regression

So I am currently trying to analyse the relationship between 3 categorical variables and their impact on the continuous/quantitative independent variable in R.

Basically, I want to analyse the impact that credit scores have on the remaining balance a customer has when they default and stop paying their loan.

Could someone tell me what kind of regression or test I could do to obtain explanatory results?
My linear regression only gives me an r squared of .27 with about 8700 observations in the initial data set.

Comment: You can have perfect coefficient estimates to do inference with and have horrible r squared values and vice-versa so definitely don't reference it as the end-all-be-all metric to judge your regression by.

Comment: Why do you think that $R^2 = 0.27$ is so awful? I would expect a ton of unexplainable variability in the data (or explained only by complex interactions of variables that are not among the three you are considering).

Comment: You're treating credit scores as categorical data?

Comment: Yes. Credit scores range from 1 to 20. If you're attributed a 1, you're risky for the bank and they will not increase your credit limit. If you get a 20, your credit limit could be increased. They are an automated process made by the bank (in my case).

Comment: Those would be ordinal data, which are kind of a hybrid of numerical and categorical data. // I thought the highest credit score was $850$.

Comment: I'm doing an internship in a bank for the summer and they operate under a different system I believe. Not sure if you are speaking of US credit scores, I'm based in Luxembourg. I don't think there's a common credit system that anyone can access, this one is strictly internal to the bank.

Answer (score 6):

You can use ANOVA as jzTUD indicates in which case you may have to use a post-hoc test such as Duncan or Bonferroni to determine which variables are significant. Alternatively, you can use multiple regression with indicator variables that although it requires a little more analysis after you get the results, it will tell you immediately which dependent variables are relevant to your model. See [Ways of comparing linear regression interepts and slopes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232040/ways-of-comparing-linear-regression-interepts-and-slopes/232041#232041).

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like an ANOVA would be appropriate, in a 3x1 design (3 predictors, 1 outcome). It can easily be done in all common statistical softwares such as R, SPSS, Matlab, etc. If a main effect on an interaction reaches significance, you can calculate a post-hoc test using only the variables of that main effect or interaction to see which way the effect goes.
On another note: Please make up your mind about what kind of test you want to run **before** you analyze your data. What you are doing now is p-hacking, looking for the test that will give you the most impressive results. Test choice should always be theory driven.